# Is there a function to report columns where data differs?

Tags: r

I have a table of presence/absence (1/0) data for species at different sites, along with their historical presence/absence. I would like to be able to list "novel" species, i.e. which columns have a presence in the new row and a 0 in the historical row.

```
site=c(1,1)
sample=c("hist","new")
speciesA=c(0,0)
speciesB=c(1,1)
speciesC=c(0,1)
df=data.frame(site,sample,speciesA,speciesB,speciesC)
df
#   site sample speciesA speciesB speciesC
# 1    1   hist        0        1        0
# 2    1    new        0        1        1
```

Is there a function that would return the just column name, in this case "speciesC"?

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```r
subset(df, select = startsWith(names(df), "species")) |>
  sapply(function(z) all(z == 0:1))
# speciesA speciesB speciesC 
#    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
```

You can use whatever column-selection method you prefer, even just `df[,-(1:2)] |> sapply(....)` in this case.

You can get just the true entries with `which`:

```r
subset(df, select = startsWith(names(df), "species")) |>
  sapply(function(z) all(z == 0:1)) |> which() |> names()
# [1] "speciesC"
```

(This does rely on the order of rows, i.e., `"hist"` before `"new"`.)

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to filter out the "false" responses and only view the true ones?

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it working with this.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably pivot your data into a long format and do this as a grouped operation:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("species")) |>
  filter(n_distinct(value) > 1, .by = c(site, name))
# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#    site sample name     value
#   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
# 1     1 hist   speciesC     0
# 2     1 new    speciesC     1
```

This gives a lot of flexibility in terms of what conditions to check (e.g., if you only want to flag changes where `hist = 0` and `new = 1`, that would be an easy change), and will give a nice regular output regardless of the number of columns input. If you just want the species names out, you can add to the end of this `... |> distinct(name)`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution combining pivot_longer with pivot_wider transformations

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(-c(site,sample),names_to = "specie", values_to = "present") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "sample",values_from = "present") %>% filter(hist == 0 & new == 1) %>%
  distinct(site,specie)
```

As a result you get info about species and site:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
   site specie  
  <dbl> <chr>   
1     1 speciesC
```

This way would be robust to NA values or unexpected values

```
site=c(1,1)
sample=c("hist","new")
speciesA=c(0,0)
speciesB=c(1,1)
speciesC=c(0,NA_integer_)
speciesD=c(0,10)
df=data.frame(site,sample,speciesA,speciesB,speciesC,speciesD)
df
# site sample speciesA speciesB speciesC speciesD
#    1   hist        0        1        0        0
#    1    new        0        1       NA       10
```